# Unsigned expression used with signed expression in assignment

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have the following code in verilog:

```
reg [5:0] a;
reg [5:0] shift_amt;
reg [63:0] mysig;

assign shift_amt = (a + 1) & 6'h3f;
assign mysig = 1 << shift_amt;
```

When I run spyglass I get the following error:

**Unsigned expression 'mysig' used with signed expression '(1 << shift_amt)' in assignment.**

I have nothing marked as **signed** or **unsigned**, and I've tried several ways of rewriting this statement, and even wrapped tried **$unsigned(1 << shift_amt)**, but for some reason that made my result for **mysig** become 0 for the test case I was using where **a = 39**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric literal `1` is implicitly a signed 32 bit value. As a matter of habit, you should write this as

```
assign mysig = 64'b1 << shift_amt;
```